# Elasticsearch analyzer tokens for alphanumeric value with dot

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I have a text field that has this value-

```
term1-term2-term3-term4-term5-RWHPSA951000155.2013-05-27.log
```

When I check using the analyze API (default analyzer), I get this -

```
    {
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "text",
            "start_offset": 2,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "term1",
            "start_offset": 9,
            "end_offset": 14,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "term2",
            "start_offset": 15,
            "end_offset": 20,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "term3",
            "start_offset": 21,
            "end_offset": 26,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "term4",
            "start_offset": 27,
            "end_offset": 32,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 5
        },
        {
            "token": "term5",
            "start_offset": 33,
            "end_offset": 38,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 6
        },
        {
            "token": "rwhpsa951000155.2013",
            "start_offset": 39,
            "end_offset": 59,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 7
        },
        {
            "token": "05",
            "start_offset": 60,
            "end_offset": 62,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 8
        },
        {
            "token": "27",
            "start_offset": 63,
            "end_offset": 65,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 9
        },
        {
            "token": "log",
            "start_offset": 66,
            "end_offset": 69,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

I am particulary curious about this token - `rwhpsa951000155.2013`.How did that happen? Currently my search for matching `RWHPSA951000155` fails because of this. How can I get it to recognize `RWHPSA951000155` and `2013` as separate tokens?

Note that if the value was `term1-term2-term3-term4-term5-RWHPSA.2013-05-27.log` then it splits `RWHPSA` and `2013` into separate tokens. So it is something to do with `951000155`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Standard Analyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html) is tokenizing `rwhpsa951000155.2013` as a product number.

> Splits words at hyphens, unless there's a number in the token, in
>   which case the whole token is interpreted as a product number and is
>   not split.

You can add a pattern analyzer to replace the '.' with a white space. The default analyzer will then tokenize the term the way you want.

```
/POST test
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "char_filter": {
                    "my_pattern": {
                        "type": "pattern_replace",
                        "pattern": "\\.",
                        "replacement": " "
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "my_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                         "char_filter": [
                            "my_pattern"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "test": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the analyze API:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty=true' -d 'term1-term2-term3-term4-term5-RWHPSA.2013-05-27.log'
```

Returns:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "term1",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 5,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "term2",
    "start_offset" : 6,
    "end_offset" : 11,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "term3",
    "start_offset" : 12,
    "end_offset" : 17,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "term4",
    "start_offset" : 18,
    "end_offset" : 23,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 4
  }, {
    "token" : "term5",
    "start_offset" : 24,
    "end_offset" : 29,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 5
  }, {
    "token" : "RWHPSA951000155",
    "start_offset" : 30,
    "end_offset" : 45,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 6
  }, {
    "token" : "2013",
    "start_offset" : 46,
    "end_offset" : 50,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 7
  }, {
    "token" : "05",
    "start_offset" : 51,
    "end_offset" : 53,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 8
  }, {
    "token" : "27",
    "start_offset" : 54,
    "end_offset" : 56,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 9
  }, {
    "token" : "log",
    "start_offset" : 57,
    "end_offset" : 60,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 10
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I kept scouring the ES documentation for how the standard analyzer works and never thought of looking at lucene's docs. BTW, I can assign an analyzer in the mappings to a field. How do I make the analyzer as the default for the index? ES docs say - "The `default_index` logical name can be used to configure a default analyzer that will be used just when indexing". Would that work? I have already defined the mappings and there's data in my index. How can I update the default analyzer alone?

Comment: Yes, it will work. In the settings example above change 'my_analyzer' to 'default_index'. To update the analyzer have a look this link: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis

Comment: I tried that and something seems to have gone wrong. I now get `{"tokens" : [ ]}` when I use the analyze API with the mentioned text. When I do `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/_settings?pretty'`, I can see the new analyzer. How do I delete all analyzers and filters and revert back to the old state? Before I never had the analysis{} section in settings.

Comment: The '.' in the filter needs to be escaped, i.e. '\\.', try and update again.

Comment: Dan, I just observed something else. It is breaking up the tokens as expected. But I'm not able to search by `RWHPSA951000155` with existing data. Before I was able to search by `RWHPSA951000155.2013`. Now that has also stopped working. I'd hate to extend this discussion further, but do you know what could possibly be causing that? Do I need to re-index my data or something?

Comment: You will need to re-index the data for the changes to take effect. The search with `RWHPSA951000155.2013` should still work as you haven't re-indexed anything and you only changed the `default_index` not the `default_search`.

Comment: I deleted the index and recreated the index and indexed the data again. I still couldn't search by `RWHPSA951000155`. I then realized that the documentation says that the index analyzer and search analyzer are different. So I added another index with name `default_search` with same definition as `default_index` and am now able to search by `RWHPSA951000155`.